# Clickable objects inside equirectangular map three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use raycaster to make objects become clickable. I have seen countless examples of this, and I have tried this code many times with no luck. The only difference I see between my example and the rest I have come across is that I am inside of a sphere.

I start my code by creating some variables (Some may not be leftover from using past examples).

```
 var container, stats;
 var camera, controls, scene, renderer, projector;
 var isUserInteracting = false;
 var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, intersected;




  var fov = 70,
  texture_placeholder,
  isUserInteracting = false,
  onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
  lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
  lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
  phi = 0, theta = 0;

  init();
  animate();
```

I continue by setting up my init() function where I set a camera and create my sphere.

```
        function init() {

            var container, mesh1;



            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "spherical_map_small.jpg" )} ) );
            mesh1.scale.x = -1;
            mesh1.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
            scene.add( mesh1 );
```

Still in the init() function, I then create a cube geometry (this is what I want to be clickable).

```
meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x33CC00});

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );

            var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x33CC00} ) );
            object.position.x = 75;
            object.position.y = 10;
            object.position.z = 0;

            object.rotation.y = 45;

            scene.add( object );

            objects.push( object );
```

Still in init(), I set up the renderer, and add some event listeners.

```
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
```

Now the problem. Next is the function that should make my box 'object' clickable, which does not seem to work. I believe I am telling it to say "works." every time an object in the scene is clicked.

I have read about raycasting with three.js for hours, and believe I have a decent understanding of how it should work, I just can not get it to work.

```
        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            isUserInteracting = false;

            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, .5 );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            raycaster.setFromCamera(vector, camera);
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene, true);

            if ( intersects.length ) {
                alert('works.');
            } 

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, try using:

```
raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
```

And have u set recursive (true) ? Otherwise it will not check the descendants

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using

    `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);`

and it still does not seem to work, I have even removed the true. I am new to Javascript and three.js, what does recursive mean?